# quick wiki solution with inline editing [and AJAX]?

Tags: looking-for-a-script, ajax, wiki

I am trying to set up a site  which will implement a fast, lightweight wiki engine:

- double click anywhere to append or change text
- press a green button to add a resource
- drag a link to reorder/add to another category
- expand or contract nodes/categories
- Ajax usage means no site refreshes

I figure someone has already done such a wiki engine.

Comment: I am in search for something like described since shut down of the notebook service by Google.
It is strange why in vast amount of existing wiki engines there is no one with good inplace editing.

Answer (score 2):

I started to post this as a comment (not an answer), but it became too long.  I don't have a specific recommendation, but I'm very interested in the answer.

--

Based on my experience, true in-line editing (which is what you're describing) is notoriously difficult to implement correctly.  What you see in most CMS's (and Wiki's) is [pop-up editing](http://clickonpublish.com/cms-encyclopedia/in-line-editing) (except they frequently call it in-line editing).

In this scenario there is an in-line **Edit** link that sends the editor somewhere else (to a sandboxed editing environment).  After the edit is saved, they are returned to their original context.  This is even used by the [StackExchange crew](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/faster-edits-with-inline-editing/).

--

Whereas true in-line editing does not remove you from your original context.  Instead, as you describe the text simply becomes editable (in place) with a click.  The only CMS I've seen accomplish this elegantly is [Squiz CMS](http://cms.squizsuite.net/features/inline-editing).  I've never used it in person, so I'm not sure how fragile or buggy this is.

--

I have, however, used in-line editing plug-ins for WordPress and they were awful.  The in-line editor would inject HTML into my page, ruin the design and the editor was extremely buggy & mis-behaved.  I abandoned them after only a few minutes.

--

As mentioned, I would love to see an answer to this question and be proven wrong, but I doubt that you'll find a Wiki that implements in-line editing in the way you describe.

Comment: good answer. If no solution exists, I am toying with the idea of implementing a simple and quick wiki....anyone interested in working together on this?